# compilation error -1073741502 Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I've got **compilation error -1073741502** while debugging from Visual Studio but not under IIS.

In logs I also found error:

**System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005):The external component created an exception**

- Deleting of ASP.NET files does not help
- Reinstalling ASP.NET does not help
- Reinstalling Visual Studio does not help

Answer (score 0):

The reason was: I kill child proccesses in **Application_Start**.

We need this for restarting child processes after site was reset.

Then you under Visual Studio there is **already** two child processes. It's look like you should not kill them for normal work.